# How to combine 2 mysql statements into 1?

Tags: php, mysql

Peter have sent request to Michelle by clicking "add friend" button on Michelle's page, database table tbl_frienRequest store Peter at "user" and store Michelle at "targetuser".

Now Peter's page must not show the "add friend" button when Michelle visiting Peter's page. Michelle's page also must not show "add friend" button when Peter visiting Michelle page.

How to write if else statement to show or not show the "add friend" button on their pages?
Currently I am using this method :

```
    $query111 = "SELECT id FROM tbl_frienRequest WHERE user='{$username1}' AND targetuser='{$username2}'";
    $result111 = mysql_query($query111,$connection) or die (mysql_error());
    confirm_query($result111);
    $requestCount = mysql_num_rows($result111);

    $query2 = "SELECT id FROM tbl_frienRequest WHERE user='{$username2}' AND targetuser='{$username1}'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2,$connection) or die (mysql_error());
    confirm_query($result2);
    $requestCount2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

if (($requestCount == 0) or ($requestCount2 == 0)){
    //show "add friend" button.
}
```

I think it works but the codes is very long, is there any other shorten codes to get the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an OR condition in your query:
i.e:

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl_frienRequest
WHERE (USER='{$username1}'
       AND targetuser='{$username2}')
  OR ( USER='{$username2}'
  AND targetuser='{$username1}'
```

Try this:

```
$query111 = "SELECT id FROM tbl_frienRequest WHERE (user='{$username1}' AND targetuser='{$username2}') OR ( user='{$username2}' AND targetuser='{$username1}')";
$result111 = mysql_query($query111,$connection) or die (mysql_error());
confirm_query($result111);
$requestCount = mysql_num_rows($result111);
if ($requestCount == 0){
            //show "add friend" button.
}
```

Comment: I heard UNION is faster than OR , info at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html

Answer (score 2):

```
$query111 = "SELECT id FROM tbl_frienRequest WHERE user in('{$username1}','{$username2}') AND targetuser in ('{$username2}','{$username2}' )";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query111 = "SELECT id FROM tbl_frienRequest WHERE (user='{$username1}' 
AND targetuser='{$username2}') 
OR user='{$username2}' AND targetuser='{$username1}'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand; you just want a single query that will return both options?  Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_frienRequest
            WHERE (user='{$username1}' AND targetuser='{$username2}')
              OR
                  (user='{$username2}' AND targetuser='{$username1}')";
```

That will return both options; the only potential trick is to figure out which is which (in case both return results).

Comment: how is possible that both return result since the page will hide the "add friend" button if 1 of them is return result?

Comment: then you shouldn't have to worry about it =] I simply mention it as a general concern with that method of combining the query

Answer (score 1):

```
 $query = "SELECT id FROM tbl_frienRequest WHERE user='{$username1}' AND targetuser='{$username2}' OR user='{$username2}' AND targetuser='{$username1}' " ;
```

AND has more precedence over OR, so you'll get the desired result with this one query